# A question about r-universal hash family definition

Tags: definition, hash-function

Here is the one possible definition of the universal hash family (from my professor's book):

A family $\{h_a | a \in A\}$ of functions $X \to Y$ is an *r-universal hash family* if, and only if, for every *r*-tupel $(x_1,...,x_r) \in X^r$ with all $x_j$ distinct, and every *r*-tuple $(y_1,...,y_r) \in Y^r$, it holds that:

$$P_{a \in A}(h_a(x_1)=y_1 \wedge...h_a(x_r)=y_r) ~=~ 1/|Y|^r$$

Generally, I understand the definition yet the one thing I found rather unclear. As we draw $a$ uniformly at random from $A$ and it should be so for every value we are hashing why the definition utilizes the same $a$ for hashing all the $r$ different inputs?

What am I missing here?

Comment: The output of a single randomly chosen hash function applied $r$ times to different inputs should have seemingly random outputs. Clearly if we chose $r$ different hash functions the random choice of them would built in some randomness that had nothing to do with the "quality" of the set of hash functions.

Comment: Can it be that these _r_ different hash functions provide the same results for different inputs with a much higher probability because of the randomness?

Comment: Perhaps an example would make it clearer: Define $\mathcal H=\{h_y\mid h_y(x)=y, y\in Y\}$. So the set of hash functions $\mathcal H$ has a constant function for each element in $Y$ mapping to that element. Then if the definition said "chose $r$ **different** hash functions" clearly this family would be $r$-universal. But not using the correct definition.

Comment: Thanks, it gets somewhat clear now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most universal family one can imagine is of size $|Y|^n$ with $n=|X|$, namely the family
$$
\{h_{(y_1,...,y_n)}\mid h_{(y_1,...,y_n)}(x_i)=y_i, (y_1,...,y_n)\in Y^n\}
$$
This family is $n$-universal. Choosing a hash function uniformly at random from this family essentially means choosing an $n$-tuple $(y_1,...,y_n)$ uniformly at random from $Y^n$. Thus any $n$-tuple output is equally likely.

---

At the other end of the scale we have the $1$-universal family I suggested in the comment section, namely
$$
\{h_y\mid h_y(x)=y, y\in Y\}
$$
where a single output from a randomly chosen function will appear random, but not more than that.

---

For $1<r<n$ we have $r$-universal families that make $r$ outputs from the same uniformly randomly chosen hash function appear uniformly random. It should appear as if $h_a$ outputs an $r$-tuple in $Y^r$ chosen uniformly at random.

Comment: "Thus any n-tuple output is equally likely" - that explains me what I've missed. Thanks again!

Comment: I am happy to hear that @ddnomad. Glad if this helped!